# discord.js DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have array which I'm cycling through via reactions on an embed. When a reaction is pressed, the message should be deleted and the function loops again. At the second reaction press, I'm getting this error:

```
(node:12908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
```

At each reaction press after the first, the amount of this error printed is doubled.

Code:

```
function movieChoiceEmbed(movies, message, count)
{
    pagecount = count;

    message.channel.send({embed: {
        color: '#D733FF',
        title: 'Choose movie',
        fields: [
            {
                name: movies[pagecount].title,
                value: movies[pagecount].description,
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: movies[pagecount+1].title,
                value: movies[pagecount+1].description,
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: '\u200b',
                value: '\u200b',
                inline: false,
            },
            {
                name: movies[pagecount+2].title,
                value: movies[pagecount+2].description,
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: movies[pagecount+3].title,
                value: movies[pagecount+3].description,
                inline: true,
            },
        ],
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
            text: 'Andrea Gafa'
        }
      }})
        .then(sentEmbed => {
            sentEmbed.react("⏪");
            sentEmbed.react("⏩");
        })
        .catch();

    client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => { // When a reaction is added
        if(user.bot) return; 

        if(reaction.emoji.name == "⏪")
        {
            await reaction.message.delete();
            count -= 4;
            movieChoiceEmbed(movies, message, count);
        }else if(reaction.emoji.name == "⏩")
        {
            await reaction.message.delete();
            count += 4;
            movieChoiceEmbed(movies, message, count);
        }
        return;
    });
}
```

I have tried deleting the last message instead with the same result:

```
await message.channel.lastMessage.delete();
```

Any clue? I'm pretty lost here.

Edit:

The messagereactionadd event being inside the function seems to be the problem. Putting it outside it fixes the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you aren’t deleting it before? Maybe in a different event or maybe you have multiple shells open

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that message isnt touched anywhere outside this function.

Comment: Does the message get deleted anyways?

Comment: Yes, the last message always gets deleted so the program is technically working. The problem is that since the number of errors is doubling each time there's a huge delay after the fourth deletion and onwards.

Comment: You are deleting it multiple times

Comment: Yes, I can understand that this might be the problem, but unless the deleted messages are cached and are trying to be deleted each time alongside the new message, I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Alright then adding a simple [catch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69273975/15781079) should work

Comment: I've tried that, but I'm now getting a modified error which can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69284708/16968113

Answer (score 0):

your error is because you're getting a promise that isn't caught.  You have several calls that are async and returning promises, one or more of them is causing an error.  I would add catch blocks to them, and then this will help you isolate where your problem lies.  For example:

```
await reaction.message.delete();
```

could be changed to:

```
await reaction.message.delete()
     .then(() { /* do something if interested */ })
     .catch(err => { console.error(err); });
```

add this to all your promised functions and you'll know where you're having issues.

Now as for the error itself, you're trying to delete a message, potentially, that has already been deleted.  Did you want to delete a reaction, or a message?  If you've deleted a message, and then try to do something with the message in the calls subsequently, then that's the problem.

Comment: thx @MrMythical, I missed the comment...typing too fast. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added that part and can now confirm that the problem originates from the message deletion. The error occurs when the reaction is pressed, so unless its trying to delete a previously deleted message it isn't really making much sense to me. And even then I've tried to delete the last message instead with the same outcome.